# Is this a solution to the equation $a|bx|+c=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was working on solving a problem in math class, and I was given this problem, $a|bx|+c=0$, as a challenge to solve. This is what I came up with.

$$
a|bx|+c=0 \\
a|bx|=-c \\
|bx|=\frac{-c}{a} \\
bx=|\frac{-c}{a}| \\
x=\pm\frac{|\frac{-c}{a}|}{b}
$$

Is this the correct way to solve this equation? I graphed the equation and found that this seems to work, but I just would like some backup on it. Thanks!

Comment: In essence, it is $\pm\frac{c}{ab}$

Comment: @imranfat Could you show how you got to that solution?

Comment: See answer Gummy bears. That's how I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well look at it this way. $|ab|$ can be written as $|a||b|$
Thus, what we get is:
$$a|b||x| + c = 0$$

Regardless of whether $b$ is positive or negative, we will always get a positive value for it after applying modulus. As $b$ is a constant, we can simply remove the modulus sign without any problem.
$$ab|x| = -c$$
$$|x| = \frac{-c}{ab}$$

As $x$ is a variable who's value we are supposed to find, upon removing modulus, we have to take both positive and negative value of its possible solution. Thus we arrive at the final result:
$$x = ±\frac{-c}{ab}$$

Comment: However remember that there will also be several cases where there are no solutions (as there are no conditions assigned to $a,b,c$). For example, if $a$ or $b$ are zero, we have no solution.

Comment: When you say that "we can simply remove the modulus sign without any problem", are you implicitly replacing $b$ with $-b$ if necessary? If so, I'm not sure I like this idea, as it hides the need to check if $-c/a$ is nonnegative before applying this formula.

Comment: @PedroM. Well as we are given no conditions, I assumed the best possible conditions for me. Otherwise, there would be several cases for this question. I did assume that $-c/a$ is positive. As $b$ will obviously be positive, we get the condition that either $c$ is negative and $a$ is positive or $c$ is positive and $a$ is negative.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake when passing from the third equation to the fourth one, it should be :

$$bx=\pm\dfrac{-c}{a}.$$

Also what are $a,b,c$? Are there any restrictions on them that can allow you to divide both sides by $a$ and $b$? What if $\tfrac{-c}{a}$ is strictly negative?

Comment: At this time $a$, $b$, and $c$ are just variables without a value, although it could look like this: $3|2x|-3=0$

Comment: @EthanBierlein So in your steps you're assuming that $a$ and $b$ are both non-zero. Now make a second case where for instance $a=0$, then ... ?

Comment: You also need to consider whether $c/a \leq 0$ or $c/a > 0$.

Comment: @PedroM. Thanks, added.